# jq: error: number and string cannot be added

Tags: type-conversion, jq

I'd like to print the value of members and id from below jq output:

```
$ cat test_|jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="AAA") | .'
{
  "name": "AAA",
  "members": 10,
  "profiles": 0,
  "templates": 0,
  "ldapGroups": 0,
  "ldapMembers": 0,
  "id": "20"
}
```

Unfortunately it works for one of each only:

```
$ cat test_|jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="AAA") | .members'
10
```

with +" "+ I get error:

```
$ cat test_|jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="AAA") | .members+" "+.id'
jq: error: number and string cannot be added
```

Comment: I had the opposite problem—wanting to _numerically_ add string fields from a JSON file that contained numbers—but your question helped me realize that there was a `tonumber` function as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63597198/785213).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I recommend to use [*string interpolation*](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)). It will automatically cast input to a string if necessary:

```
jq -r '.[]|select(.name=="AAA")|"\(.members) \(.id)"' file.json
```

Answer (score 22):

Convert number to string with `tostring` function:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="AAA") | (.members|tostring) +" "+ .id test'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified precisely how you want the two values to appear, so it is worth pointing out that you could write:

```
.... | (.members, .id)
```

or

```
 .... | [.members, .id]
```

or

```
.... | [.members, .id] | E
```

where E could be @csv or @tsv or etc. In jq 1.5, `join/1` will also do the type conversion.

Comment: The OP mentioned `.members+" "+.id'` in the question which gives them the "number and string cannot be added" error. Imo that's quite clear.

Comment: Which means using `[.members, .id] | join(" ")`.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by just projecting the members of interest. e.g

```
$ jq -Mc '.[] | select(.name=="AAA") | {members,id}' data.json
{"members":10,"id":"20"}
```

Now you can see `.members` is a number and `.id` is a string.  You can't add them directly with `+` but you can choose any of the options explained in the other answers.