# How to sum up string fields that contain percentages with 'jq'?

Tags: json, math, type-conversion, jq

I have a JSON file that's keeping track of column widths for a table as percentages. So the input file, `columns.json`, looks something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Column A",
    "width": "33%"
  },
  {
    "name": "Column B",
    "width": "33%"
  },
  {
    "name": "Column C",
    "width": "33%"
  },
  {
    "name": "Column D",
    "visible": false
  }
]
```

Some columns are not displayed and therefore don't have widths (`jq '.[].width'` will return `null`s for these), and then there's also the issue of the percent signs. Otherwise I might've used `munge | munge | paste -sd+ | bc`, which is usually what I use for summing things up in the shell, but that seems stupid here because `jq` *ought* to be able to do this by itself.

So **using only `jq`**, how can I sum up the `width` fields from this file, *e.g.*, to make sure they don't exceed 100%?

### Things I have tried (that didn't work)

I use `select(.)` here to filter out records that don't have a `.width`, then get rid of the percent sign:

```sh
jq '[.[].width | select(.) | sub("%"; "")] | add' columns.json
```

…but that just concatenates the strings and returns `"333333"`.

I didn't see any mention of the word "typecast" in the `jq` man page, so I thought maybe it would do type inference, treating a string that looks like a number as a number in the right context:

```sh
jq '[.[].width | select(.) | sub("%"; "") | .+0] | add' columns.json
```

…but that just yields and error message like:

```
jq: error (at columns.json:18): string ("33") and number (0) cannot be added
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter alternative:

```
map(.width[:-1] | tonumber?) | add
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IqWchEeFpv)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution, and I've proposed some edits to round out your answer. You can tell I spend a lot of time in `sed`, since I didn't even _consider_ using a slice instead of a search-and-replace. `:)`

Comment: Oh well, they didn't clear the review queue. Marking as the accepted solution anyway. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911763/jq-error-number-and-string-cannot-be-added) gave me the clue that there was a `tostring` function, so a more thorough search of the manual page revealed that the analogous function for numbers is `tonumber`.

Well, duh. I guess I was expecting it to be named something else, like `toint`, which is why I didn't find it while string-searching through the man page.

Here is the solution I ended up with:

```sh
jq 'map(.width | sub("%"; "")? | tonumber) | add' columns.json
```

Instead of `select(.)` to filter out the `null`s from objects with no `.width` field, I just silently ignore the error in `sub` (with `?`), which drops those records.

Note that `map(.width)` is just another way of saying `[.[].width]`.